# How to get random line string from .txt file from resources?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a text file in my resources called TextIPS (contains a list of about 4000 IP addresses)

I want a function that is able to get a random line of that text file and then write it to a textbox.

Let's say the text file contains 5 lines

1. 127.0.0.1
2. 192.168.1.1
3. 69.27.12.31
4. 83.31.64.12
5. 90.137.28.73

When I click a button I want it to fetch any of these 5 values and then write the fetched value into a textbox.

Comment: Create an array containing the text file lines. Generate a random integer and get one of the array items by its index using the randomly generated integer.

Comment: Please make an attempt at writing the code. Then if you run into trouble, post the code and ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of code :

```
Private rdm As New Random

Private Function GetRandom(max As Integer) As Integer
    'rdm.Next(minValue, maxValue) returns a random number greater than or equal to minValue and less than maxValue.
    Return rdm.Next(0, max)
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim IpAddresses() As String = File.ReadAllLines(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\TextIPS.txt")
    Dim RandomIpAddress As String = IpAddresses(GetRandom(IpAddresses.Length))
    MsgBox(RandomIpAddress)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't create a new `Random` object every time you want a random number. Move the declaration of `rdm` **outside** of the `GetRandom` function. `Private rdm As New Random`.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind I figured it out. I uploaded the ip's to a raw pastebin page and added this code

```
 Dim wc As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim r As New Random
    Dim RndIpAddress As String() = wc.DownloadString(IPAddressList).Split(Environment.NewLine)
    ParseIP(RndIpAddress(r.Next(1, RndIpAddress.Length)))
```

using IPAddressList as the link to raw pastebin page